# line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, anaconda

Today, I tried to write variables in my bash_profile file. So when I initialised the necessary variables and saved the file. This error showed up.
Can anyone please help me ?

[image]

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

error:

[image: The error that I am getting is:]

Comment: Are you sure it's `/Users/mac/.bash_profile` what you show here? The error indicates the contents of the file is quite different.

Comment: yes, I copy pasted the same.

Comment: Line 3 doesn't contain the characters shown in the error.

Comment: The screenshot you posted on line 3 has a comment, code has `__conda_setup` line. Please inspect the file in a hex editor, try `hexdump -C` or `cat -v` and see for any invisble characters.

Comment: Just a remark passing by: Loading conda in your .bash_profile or .bashrc is harmful for your environment (it will most likely break other python programs). Encapsulate it in a shell function so that you can load it when it's really needed.

Comment: How can I encapsulate it ?

Comment: How can I use this ? hexdump -C?

Comment: @AnnieDhawan add a line with `conda_init() {` just before the first `# >>> conda init >>>` and a line with `}; export -f conda_init` just after the second `# >>> conda init >>>`; then, when you start a terminal , you'll have a function named_`conda_init` that'll run the encapsulated code